# Classifying with sci-kit learn for multi-valued output

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Let us say I have chosen a single training document from a training set.  I have put it into feature vector X for my chosen features.

I am trying to do:

```
self.clf = LogisticRegression()
self.clf.fit(X, Y)
```

My Y would be something like:
`[0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0]`

I would like to train my one single model so that it best fits each of the 11 output values simultaneously.  This doesn't seem to work for `fit` as I get a `unhashable type 'list'` error because it is expecting a single value which is ether binary or multi-class but does not allow for more than one value.

Is there anyway to do this with sci-kit learn?

Comment: I suppose I could encode each output as it comes along into a value between 0 and 2^11 - 1, but is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multi-label classification has a somewhat different API than ordinary classification. Your `Y` should be a sequence of sequences, e.g. a list of lists, like

```
Y = [["foo", "bar"],          # the first sample is a foo and a bar
     ["foo"],                 # the second is only a foo
     ["bar", "baz"]]          # the third is a bar and a baz
```

Such a `Y` can then be fed to an estimator that handles multiple classifications. You can construct such an estimator using the `OneVsRestClassifier` wrapper:

```
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression())
```

then train with `clf.fit(X, Y)`. `clf.predict` will now produce sequences of sequences as well.

**UPDATE** as of scikit-learn 0.15, this API is deprecated because its input is ambiguous. You should convert the `Y` I gave above to a matrix with a `MultiLabelBinarizer`:

```
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
>>> mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
>>> mlb.fit_transform(Y)
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0]])
```

Then feed this to an estimator's `fit` method. Converting back is done with `inverse_transform` on the *same* binarizer:

```
>>> mlb.inverse_transform(mlb.transform(Y))
[('bar', 'foo'), ('foo',), ('bar', 'baz')]
```

Comment: Sorry, I must have been too loose in my terminology.  Upon applying `OneVsRestClassifier`, the test document I have entered relying on the entire 250,000 document training set came back with `[(0,)]` as the output for `predict` instead of a predictor for all 11 items.  I am getting a `UserWarning: Label 0 is present in all training examples.` even though there definitely are a number of unique combinations of the 11 items fed into the `fit` function.  So into `fit` I have something like `Y=[[0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],...]`

Comment: @demongolem: `Y` must be a sequence of sequences of labels, not an indicator matrix.

Comment: Ah, so if I get you properly, I want to say document X is a 4 and a 5 using the terminology I use in the other answer's comments as `[4,5]` instead of encoding it to 11 binary values?  If that is the case, how would I state that X lacks all 11 labels?  Could I use an empty list to do this or do I have to create a 12th label to accomplish this?

Comment: @demongolem: yes, that's what I meant. The lists will be converted to indicator matrices internally, but supporting those in the API would be complicated because of ambiguities (any indicator matrix can also be viewed as a list of lists of labels). The empty list represents no labels.

Comment: @demongolem: btw., an indicator matrix can be turned into the expected format quite with `np.where`, e.g. `Y = [[0,0,1], [1,0,0]]; [np.where(y)[0] for y in Y]` produces `[array([2]), array([0])]` which is acceptable for `OneVsRestClassifier`.

Comment: OT larsmans: you call this multi-output but in sklearn terminology multi-output is something else and actually works with label arrays ;) - btw why don't we support indicator matrices?

Comment: @AndreasMueller: multi-label is multi-output, except in a classification setting. I think `LabelBinarizer` actually supports this, but as I said earlier, it might be ambiguous.

Comment: I thought we called the thing in decision trees multi output? and that is different from multi-label. and also classification.

Comment: @AndreasMueller I haven't been using the decision trees yet, but I changed the answer to reflect sklearn terminology anyway. (This problem has various names in the literature too...)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please be more specific what your task is?
Is a label a fixed length vector of binary variables? Then this would be called multi label classification (i.e. multiple labels are either on or off).
If each label can have more than two values it is called "multi output" in scikit-learn and can only be done by trees and ensembles.

PS: if you use a linear classifier such as logistic regression, the output variables will be treated independently any way.

Comment: To answer your question, I have a bunch of human-annotated documents.  Document X shows or shows not quality 1.  Document X shows or shows not quality 2 ... Document X shows or shows not quality 11.  Therefore, each label is exactly 11 binary values and would be multi-label according to your description.  Perhaps all 11 could be treated as all independent of each other, however from my understanding of the subject matter, there is some dependence exhibited.  That is if Document X shows 4 it is also very likely that it shows 5 as well.